# My sticky nav bar isn't working/ partially working

Tags: html, navigation, navbar

I'd like to make a sticky nav bar like the one in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_sticky

However, when I add the `positon: sticky;` property to the  element in my code it works and the nav bar sticks after scrolling but when i scroll further down it goes away.

I would like it so that the nav bar is sticky just like the one in the example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="homebackground">
<head>
  <title>
    Apex Legends Fan-site
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/cssfile.css">
</head>
<body class="homebackground">
  <header>
    <img src="../Images/Logo/apexlogo.png" height=150px; class="center">
  </header>
  <nav class="sticky">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="../Home/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../Legends/legends.html">Legends</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="border">
    <button class="btn"> <img src="../Images/Body_Images/apexlegends.jpg" width="40%" class="center1"> </button>
  </div>
  <section>
    <p class="pcontainer">
      Apex Legends is a free-to-play first-person shooter battle royale game developed by Respawn
      Entertainment
      and
      published by Electronic Arts. It was released for Microsoft Windows, PlayStation 4, and Xbox
      One on February
      4, 2019, without any prior announcement or marketing. A Nintendo Switch version is planned
      for release in
      late 2020, along with cross-platform play between all supported platforms set to release on
      October 6, 2020.
    </p>
    <img src="../Images/Body_Images/image1.jpg" class="center" width="50%">
    <p class="pcontainer"> In Apex Legends, up to 20 three-person squads or 30 two-person duos land
      on an island and
      search for weapons
      and supplies before attempting to defeat all other players in combat. The available play area
      on the island
      shrinks over time, forcing players to keep moving or else find themselves outside the play
      area which can be
      fatal. The final team alive wins the round. The game is set in the same science fiction
      universe as Respawn
      Entertainment's Titanfall and Titanfall 2.</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* Header */

header h1 {
  color: firebrick;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to left, black 45%, rgb(94, 5, 5));
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Navigation Bar */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 19.8%;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
nav li a:last-child {
font-size: 13px;
}

}*/

nav li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Background */

.homebackground {
  background-image: url("../Images/background/background1.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .homebackground {
    background-image: url("../Images/background/background.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.legendsbackground {
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

/* For positioning images */

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.center1 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/* For hover-highlight in Legends Section */

.octane {
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 70%;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.green :hover {
  background-image: url(../Images/Legends_pics/octanechibihover.png);
}

/* For assigning properties to divs */

.border {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 4px solid #953036;
  background-color: #953036;
}

/* Paragraph Containers */

.pcontainer {
  color: aliceblue;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid #953036;
  background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: could you please rearrange your code so i can see it properly ?

Comment: How would you like me to re-arrange it?

Comment: just edit your code & make it runable, and i assume that you are new to stackoverflow. follow their steps. Or if you don't have time you can send the code on my twitter account.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to stackoverflow. How do I make it runable? Are you talking about those "fiddle" thingys?

Comment: Alright, I tried it in JSFiddle but the images aren't loaded becuase they are saved locally on my PC.
https://jsfiddle.net/bkmeg6cf/
Thank you for your help
You can see here that the nav bar dissappears after scrolling too far down

Comment: Trying the code you provided, I can't replicate the error you mention. You can see a working codepen of it [here](https://codepen.io/lucasreta/pen/PozNvLr). It scrolls down and the sticky `nav` follows you along.